# Luracast\Restler: NGINX 404 not found

Tags: php, api, nginx, restler

I'm trying to install luracast restler on nginx + php7.1 but I always get the following output. (On localhost with apache + php 7.1 everything works fine)

```html
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    },
    "debug": {
        "source": "Routes.php:431 at route stage",
        "stages": {
            "success": [
                "get"
            ],
            "failure": [
                "route",
                "negotiate",
                "message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I try resources.json I get this:

```html
{
    "apiVersion": "1",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.1",
    "basePath": "https://api.example.com/api",
    "produces": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "apis": []
}
```

NGINX.conf:

```html
server {
  listen *:443 ssl http2;
  server_name api.example.com;
  keepalive_timeout 70;

  root /var/www/public;

  # Security
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains" always;
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

  fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

  location /api/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
     fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index  index.php;
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include fastcgi.conf;
  }

  location ~ \.(aspx|jsp|cgi)$ {
     return 410;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
     deny  all;
  }

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

index.php:

```html
<?php

require_once 'vendor/restler.php';

use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
use Luracast\Restler\Defaults;

Luracast\Restler\Resources::$hideProtected = false;
Defaults::$crossOriginResourceSharing = true;
Defaults::$accessControlAllowOrigin   = '*';
Defaults::$accessControlAllowMethods  = 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD';

$r = new Restler();

$r->addAPIClass('Resources');
$r->addAPIClass('Explorer');

$r->addAPIClass('Controller\User');
$r->addAPIClass('Controller\Place');
$r->addAPIClass('Controller\Event');
$r->addAPIClass('Controller\Post');
$r->addAPIClass('Controller\Login');
$r->addAPIClass('Controller\Register');

$r->addAuthenticationClass('Controller\AccessControl');

$r->handle();
```

On localhost with apache all works fine and I get the following output:

```html
{
    "apiVersion": "1",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.1",
    "basePath": "http://localhost/api",
    "produces": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "apis": [
        {
            "path": "/resources/user.{format}",
            "description": "Class User"
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/place.{format}",
            "description": "Class Place"
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/event.{format}",
            "description": "Class Event"
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/post.{format}",
            "description": "Class Post"
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/login.{format}",
            "description": "Class Login"
        },
        {
            "path": "/resources/register.{format}",
            "description": "Class Register"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also tried composer update to update the generated autoload routes. But doesn't work. Does anyone have an answer?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Restler is working fine, that's why you get JSON output :)

But your classes does not seem to load.

Try to include them manually and see if it fixes the issue!

Then you can try `/user/{id}` and see if it works!

Comment: Doesnt work for me. When i try to route on for example https://api.example.com/api/user/705 it doesnt work but as i said on localhost with apache all fine. (http://localhost/api/user/705)

Comment: It looks like it is not loading your classes at all. Restler classes like resources, load just fine. Did you make sure the classes are loadable? If you are using `composer` make sure you run `composer install` on the server

Comment: Updated my answer above

Comment: Tried composer install / update and dump-autoload. But also doenst work for me.

Comment: See if you are able to manually include a API class with `require` in index.php

Comment: For example, instead of  `$r->addAPIClass('Controller\User');` use `$r->addAPIClass(Controller\User::class);`

Comment: It works if i manually include a API class with require in index.php. But this is not the right solution here i think.

Comment: I changed psr0 to psr4 to load controller and core classes. Now controller classes load as excepted but the other classes like entities dont load. (Internal Server Error: Class 'Core\\Entity\\User' does not exist)